# Can't include generated protobuf files in cpp file

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have a problem regarding generated protobuf files which wont include in my C++ source files.

Project structure :

```
src/
├── Folder/
│    ├── file1.cpp
│    └── file2.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Proto/
│    ├── protofile.proto
│    └── CMakeLists.txt
└── Build/
```

`CMakeLists.txt` in Proto folder:

```
INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HDRS protofile.proto)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HDRS PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
add_library(protoLib ${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HDRS})
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` in main folder:

```
...
add_subdirectory(Proto)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PUBLIC protoLib)
...
```

The proto file generates fine to the build folder as `protofile.pb.cc` and `protofile.pb.h` but when I try to include it in `file1.cpp` it wont find it

```
#include <Proto/protofile.pb.h>
...
```

Comment: I haven't worked for some time with protobuf already, but are you sure that generated src and headers are in Proto directory, not in build directory? Try `get_filename_component(PROTO_HDRS_DIR ${PROTO_HDRS} DIRECTORY)`

Comment: When I ran that I got the following:
`PROTO_HDRS_DIR=projectRoot/build/src/Protobuf`

Comment: O great, so you got your answer. I would solve it by `target_include_directories(protoLib ${PROTO_HDRS_DIR} PUBLIC)`

Comment: Should I set this in the CMakeList in src or in Proto?

Comment: Can be done in different ways, but most clean to me seems: in Proto/CMakeLists.txt get the directory of proto headers, and call `target_include_directories(protoLib ......`  , then when you link with your target `protoLib` somewhere else in another CMakeLists it will propagate the include directories and you will be able to `#include "protofile.pb.h"`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me with the addition to also add `${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR}` to `target_include_directories`